# Automated theorem proofing for mathematical induction

Tags: math

If there is a way to implement a proofer for mathematical induction, how would it look like? If it is not possible, why?

I thought about a way where you specify basic axioms and rules as an input and restrict it to problems with basic sums and equations.

Would it be the same way for mathematical proofs in general?

Comment: By "proofer" do you mean an algorithm that finds a proof for a given statement? Turing showed that is not possible to do in general. If you mean a machine that churns out proofs based on given axioms, that is possible. But induction is such a major part of axiomatic number theory that almost all proofs use induction at one stage or another.

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep the answer limited to induction over the natural numbers.

Let `S(n)` be the statement you want to proof by induction for all `n`. Then the program will need to check: `S(0)` and `S(n) => S(n+1)`.

The first part is as hard as proving some statement, the second part is about proving the equivalence of two such statements. This means, even if the first part is not hard, the second part might be `NP-hard` (to my knowlegde). So yes, a proofer may be implemented (just need to check the one statement and the equivalence of two statements) but I don't think you can guarantee it terminating.

Comment: BTW, not all the proofs start from S(0). In many cases you start from a constant and then assume for n and then prove for n+1.

Comment: @GoodLuck you can make every proof starting from a constant start from 0